# Drawing line WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to draw a line by clicking and moving cursor from point to point, I've just copied following code any my WindowProcedure looks like that:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   
    //PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    bool draw = false;
    int x = 0, y=0;

    //InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            draw = true;
            x = LOWORD(lParam);
            y = HIWORD(lParam);
            return 0;

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        if (draw)
        {
            hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            MoveToEx(hdc, x, y, NULL);
            LineTo(hdc, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        }
        draw = FALSE;
        return 0;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        if (draw)
        {
            hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            MoveToEx(hdc, x, y, NULL);
            LineTo(hdc, x = LOWORD(lParam), y = HIWORD(lParam));
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        }
        return 0;


    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
   }
```

But when i click nothing happens, it is just like only one case at time can be handled, is it correct? When I comment first two cases it draws lines,so it enters to switch but it is not what i wanted to do. Any advices?

Comment: This isn't how painting works. Do your painting in response to WM_PAINT.

Comment: Ok, i did something like:
case WM_PAINT:
  if (draw)
  {
   hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
   SetPixel(hdc, x, y, RGB(50, 50, 50));
   ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
   
  }
  return 0; 
and it still doesn't work. @Edit, i guess i can't add code to comment...

Comment: No, that's not how to do it either. Don't guess. Dont make this up. Study the topic. Nobody learnt to program Win32 by guessing.

Comment: Notice that `draw` is a local variable.

Comment: `x` and `y` will always be zero when you invokve `MoveToEx`.  Do you see why?

Comment: I believe you need to set a pen.  `GetStockObject(BLACK_PEN)` followed by `SelectObject(...)` ...

Comment: if you use WM_PAINT, it's as follows → "case WM_PAINT: if (draw) { PAINTSTRUCT ps; hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); SetPixel(hdc, x, y, RGB(50, 50, 50)); EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); } return 0;"
though that is not why it doesn't work.

Comment: @David Heffernan You only don't know C language.

Answer (score -2):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   
    //PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    static bool draw = false;  // ←static
    static int x = 0, y=0;     // ←
```

How about this?

Comment: Pen setting is not required. WM_PAINT also is not required.

Comment: Without handling WM_PAINT your drawing will be erased when the window gets refreshed (try to move window out of the screen and back in or minimize and restore).

Comment: This is obvious. And in the case of WM_PAINT, InvalidateRect() also is required first.

Comment: What you think is obvious clearly isn't to the asker. This is an answer of very low quality. How about this? Is that the best explanation you can provide.

Comment: You don't have the right to say that. You just only said 'Study the topic'.

Comment: @David Heffernan If you use WM_PAINT, coordinate retention data is required. Though you don't know how to retain data.
Therefore, it can be said that you have never written a program by using WM_PAINT. A global variable is not required any where.

Comment: @nariuji there's a difference between a comment and an answer. Your answer will only leave the OP with more questions.

Comment: Instead of looking critically at what you wrote, let's go on a voting spree. Classy.